# Excel - Formula to create an array of lookup values based on a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was looking for the solution for this apparently easy problem, but failed so far. I have a table in Excel like this:

```
Column 1   Column 2
apples        1
apples        2
bananas       5
apples        3
bananas       4
```

What I need is a formula that returns an array of the values in column 2, based on the criteria on column 1. So if I choose "apples", my output array should be {1,2,3}. That output should be compatible for use inside of a standard SUM(SUMIFS()) formula.

Thanks in advance for any insight

Regards,
André

Edit: The order of the elements in the output array is unimportant

Comment: If the 1 and 2 were swapped in your example would you then want the output to be {2,1,3} (based on the order they occur) or still {1,2,3} (sorted ascending)?

Comment: The order doesn´t matter. It can be either {1,2,3} or {2,1,3}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you **don't** want something like this

`=IF(A2:A6="apples",B2:B6,"")`

For your example that will return your values along with "null strings" like this

`{1;2;"";3;""}`

You could use this version to return the values in ascending order

`=SMALL(IF(A2:A6="apples",B2:B6),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(A2:A6,"apples"))))`

That will give you

`{1;2;3}`

If you use that in another formula you'll need to "array enter" with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Barry, for the swift answer. Your formula worked perfectly. However, upon working a little further, I came upon an unexpected problem: I need also to make sure the output array contains unique items only. The numbers in the original data are repeated in multiple rows, but my SUM(SUMIFS()) can only count them once. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that's possible but probably quite complex - it might be worth you considering a different approach - you could use MATCH to compare your range to the output of `=IF(A2:A6="apples",B2:B6,"")` and then whether there were blanks or duplicates in that range it wouldn't matter.....