# Return array of values based on criteria

Tags: excel

I am attempting to create an Excel formula to return an array of values based on logic.

I am aware of Excel functions like `SUMIFS` that accept parameters for range and condition, but instead of returning a sum of range, I want to return a (cell overflow) array of values based on condition.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828409/1837874) helped, but I do not want the return array to be sorted. I need the array indexes to be the same as if they were filtered.

Example cells:

```
Name     Type        Shares      Price
STA      Buy         12          5.7
STA      Buy         15          3.8
STA      Buy         100         5.4
STA      Sell       -50          5.8
GA       Buy         55          3.55
```

Current formula:

```
# works but sorted least to greatest, want to return non sorted
=SMALL(IF((NameRange="STA")*(TypeRange="Buy"),PriceRange),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIFS(NameRange,"STA", TypeRange,"Buy"))))
```

This returns:

```
3.80
5.40
5.70
```

I am attempting to return non-sorted, as in original display order of matches:

```
5.7
3.8
5.4
```

Comment: Do you have access to the `FILTER` formula?

Comment: Thanks - Filter seems to be just what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to  <kbd>Microsoft 365</kbd>  you can use `FILTER` to produce your output:

```
=FILTER(D2:D6,(A2:A6=H3)*(B2:B6=H4))
```

---

[image]

---

*You could also return your values in a comma seperate string by nesting the above formula in `TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, [FORMULA ABOVE])` which would yield `5.7, 3.8, 5.4`*

Comment: BOOM! Filter is the best.